# Best way to get into playing D&D?

Tags: dnd-5e

Okay so I have a friend who's recently started playing D&D and me and a bunch of other people have said that we would want to join in. However, we're worried that we'll be a bit clueless and are wondering the best ways to get into D&D. Thanks

Comment: I voted to close as "unclear what you're asking," not necessarily as a duplicate. Can you take a look at the two linked duplicate-candidates and--if they don't help you out--edit your question to make clear what you're still looking for?

Comment: Yep, both of those helped me, Thanks for telling me :)